# Is it possible to have Facebook displayed in the old, pre-2013 layout?

Tags: facebook

I wonder if one can have someone's Facebook timeline displayed in the old, pre-2013 layout/format? That is the short version of my question, which if you know the answer to, it will suffice. The explanation why I need this is given below:

What I need this for:
I have a backup of a person's entire Facebook timeline for over 7 years along with notes, images and comments. I recently became a friend of this person and discovered that he posted a lot of material "for friends only" and would like to create a new backup with the additional information, but I would rather update the old backup with the "friends only" information as the original backup contained many images and links to articles which aren't available anymore and which I would like to preserve. So is it possible to have a Facebook displayed in the old, pre-2013 layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can’t go back to old Facebook layouts. Not online at least. What you are trying to do might be possible offline, programatically, but it involves some work on your behalf.

Comment: Any advice, perhaps?

Comment: Well, theoretically, you should save the content you want to backup and then edit the layout to make it look like the old one, but it’s neither an easy nor a rapid one.

Comment: You could try to save it in an abstract format, like JSON or something and then stitch it to the old layout. But again, it’s not the easiest thing to do.

Comment: I have the old, pre-2013 style, backup which I just have to update with the additional posts, so it is doable. Thanks!